# Repository - Filtro de Registros de acordo com permissão do usuário

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, spring-jpa

Pesquisando sobre como filtrar os registros com os repository, encontrei as anotações:

- @PreAuthorize
- @PreFilter
- @PostFilter

Tem 2 Roles no sistema: ROLE_ADMIN e ROLE_USER sendo que o ROLE_ADMIN pode acessar todos os registros, o ROLE_USER pode acessar somente seus registros, com base em condições de colunas da tabela, o que recomendam?

- Fazer um método diferente pra cada tipo de usuário e usar o controlador para gerenciar qual método usar?
- Usar os filtros no repository?

Percebi que o @PostFilter retorna tudo e somente depois filtra, retornando tudo e depois filtrando, deixando a consulta mais lenta, e o @PreFilter apresenta a exceção abaixo:

@PreFilter("filterObject.id == 7")

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A PreFilter expression was set but the method argument typeclass java.lang.String is not filterable
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.findFilterTarget(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.before(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:50)
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:72)
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:40)
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.findAllByIdentificadorRelacionamentoOcorrencia(Unknown Source)
at br.com.teste.controller.OcorrenciaRegistroFuncionarioControllerImpl.listar(OcorrenciaRegistroFuncionarioControllerImpl.java:36)
at br.com.teste.controller.OcorrenciaController.init(OcorrenciaController.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
at org.joinfaces.annotations.ViewScope.get(ViewScope.java:42)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:55)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:356)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getBoolean(TagAttributeImpl.java:150)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.IfHandler.apply(IfHandler.java:91)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:206)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possibilidade simples, que é baseada no usuário autenticado, não necessidando criar mais endpoint, é fazer um filtro no `repository`, conforme exemplo abaixo:

#### Controler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clientes",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Cliente>> getClientes() throws URISyntaxException {
    List<Cliente> clientes;
    if (SecurityUtils.isCurrentUserInRole(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)) {
        clientes= clienteRepository.findAll();
    } else {
        clientes= clienteRepository.findByUserIsCurrentUser();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(clientes, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

#### Repository

```
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente,Long> {

    @Query("select Clientes from Clientes clientes where clientes.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
    List<Cliente> findByUserIsCurrentUser();
    
}
```

#### Util

```
public final class SecurityUtils {

    private SecurityUtils() {
    }

    public static boolean isCurrentUserInRole(String authority) {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            return authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .anyMatch(grantedAuthority -> grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals(authority));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Um ótimo exemplo opensource com a stack Spring Boot + Angular a ser estudado é o [JHipster](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app).

Comment: Obrigado Murillo, vou estudar.